# Again.. The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm stuck with a strange behavior.. I have an action which returns Excel file:

```
   public ActionResult AgentPortfolioReport(DateTime fromDate, DateTime toDate)
   {
        ...

        return File(ms.ToArray(), "application/vnd.ms-excel", "SomeReport.xlsx");
   }
```

Then I put in my view:

```
 @Html.ActionLink("Get Report", "AgentPortfolioReport", new { fromDate = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-15), toDate = DateTime.Today }, new { @class = "iin-submit", id = "loadPortfolio" })
```

Everything works great, file is downloaded. Then variable dates come into play. I try to make in with a clean javascript with a function:

```
function LoadReport(action, fromDate, toDate) {
        window.location = '/Reports/' + action + '?fromDate=' + encodeURIComponent(fromDate) + '&toDate=' + encodeURIComponent(toDate);
    }
```

And boom! I get an exception:

```
The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'toDate' of non-nullable type 'System.DateTime' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult AgentPortfolioReport(System.DateTime, System.DateTime)' in 'AgentsNetwork.Controllers.ReportsController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.
Parameter name: parameters
```

I also tried to work it out with a form like this:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("AgentPortfolioReport", "Reports", FormMethod.Get))
{ 
  <div>
    Укажите период:<br/>
    <label for="fromDate">C </label>
    <input id="fromDate" name="fromDate" type="text" />
    <label for="toDate"> по </label>
    <input id="toDate" name="toDate" type="text" />
  </div>
  <p>
    <input type="submit" value="Get report" />
  </p>
}
```

But the result is the same. Adding nullable id parameter didn't help. Please give me a hint what's wrong..

Comment: When does the exception occur? When the form is posted? Also, are you using any custom model binders?

Comment: @newmanth request even does not hit an action. So when I click on a button I get that error. No custom model binders is user. The strange thing is that with Acitonlink everything works fine..

Comment: So, I think your issue may be to globalization settings. What format are your date entries? For example, are you using "30.4.2016" or "30/4/2016", or something else?

Comment: Can you show the actual url's generated by each of the 3 options you used. If the `ActionLink()` is working, then the `BeginForm()` will also work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, MVC uses an invariant culture in its model binder. Unfortunately, this causes the DateTime parser to break if you provide the binder a date/time format that doesn't match. To overcome this, you can create a custom model binder like so, changing the [culture code](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee825488(v=cs.20).aspx), as appropriate:

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Web.Mvc;

public class DateTimeBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        ValueProviderResult value = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName);
        return value.ConvertTo(typeof(DateTime), new CultureInfo("ru-RU"));
        }
    }
}
```

Add the following two lines to your `Application_Start()` method in `Global.asax.cs`:

```
ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(DateTime), new DateTimeBinder());
ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(DateTime?), new DateTimeBinder());
```

Comment: This does not address OP's issue, which is why the value if `null` - if a date was sent in a different format from the server culture and binding failed, the value of the properties would be `1/1/0001` (not `null`, and there would be no exception)

Comment: That's not true, I verified it myself. If the date is entered in a format different from the application culture, then a runtime exeception is thrown. For example, if you were to enter 30.4.2016 (not valid with invariant culture, but a valid Russian date format), the default binder will fail and an exception will be thrown. But if you add the custom binder above, the value is passed correctly.

Comment: OP has claimed that making the paramater nullable still throws the error so the format/culture makes no difference. This is not OP's issue.

Comment: @StephenMuecke I claimed that adding nullable `id` parameter as stated in default route generated with the project in VS didn't help. That was the most popular answer for such problem. Seemed that custom model binder  fixed the problem. As for generated URL's I checked them at first and didn't find any differences..

Comment: @IDeveloper, If you had made the parameters nullable as claimed (i.e `DateTime? fromDate, DateTime? toDate`) then that exception could not possible have occurred - the values would have been set to `1/1/0001` :)